# C++ multilevel inheritance function calls

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider multilevel inheritance between C++ classes. Consider:

```
struct A { 
    void Dummy1() { }
};

struct B : A { 
    void Dummy1() { }
};

struct C : B {
    void Dummy() { 
        Dummy1(); 
    }

    void Dummy1() { }
};

struct D : C { 
    void Dummy1() { }
};

struct E : D { 
    void Dummy1() { }
};
```

Given:

```
E e;
e.Dummy();
```

I want to know which Dummy1 would be called. The one defined in class `C` or the one defined in class `E`?

Also, I get very confused in function call made in multilevel inheritance, like in case of virtual functions etc. Can some one suggest a book or article which can help me in understanding this. I googled a lot but was not able to find anything helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know which `Dummy1` would be called. The one defined in class `C` or the one defined in class `E`?

Given your code, it will call the one defined in `C`.

If you want it to call the one defined in `E`, you'll have to make `Dummy1` a `virtual` function.

Answer (score 1):

The principle you want to learn is called **polymorphism**.

If the `Dummy1()` is defined as `virtual` in all classes then the version will be used which is defined in the exact class of the object, i.e. in your case `E::Dummy()`.

However in your code it is not `virtual` that's why you will have `C::Dummy()` called

Mind that most compilers will give a warning that you're overriding a function if `virtual` is not provided when inheriting (and function definition matches)